# Geany not running Python

Tags: python, geany

I'm a new user of Python

I installed Python35 for Windows. Hello.py runs fine in a terminal.
When trying to run the same in Geany the path is not found.

These are the settings in Geany:

Compile: C:\Python35\python -m py_compile "%f"

Execute: C:\Python35\python  ¨%f¨

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You could try using PyCharm. Unless you have very low specs on your computer and can only use Geany, for some reason

Comment: What is the exact error message? Where is your Python script stored?

Comment: Maybe try to reinstall geany

Answer (score 1):

> Execute: C:\Python35\python ¨%f¨

This string contains the diaeresis character (¨) (U+00A8) instead of the double quote (") (U+0022).

Comment: Yes, the quotes do really look funny ;)